# Calculate duration of zero coupon bond

Tags: risk-management, duration

I am currently studying interest rate risk management, and i can't seem to get the derivation right, and I would like to do all of the steps, to be sure that I understand what is going on.

**Let Pz (t, T ) be the price of a zero coupon bond at time t with maturity T and continuously compounded interest rate r.**

Duration = $-\frac{1}{P} \frac{d P}{d r}$

Let A and a be two constants and x be a variable. Let $F(x)=A \times e^{a x}$
be a function of x. Then, the first derivative of F with respect to x, denoted by $\frac{d F}{d x}$, is
given by

Derivative of F(x) with respect to  $x=\frac{d F}{d x}=A \times a \times e^{a x}=a \times F(x)$

The book shows (duration of zero coupon bond):
$D_{z, T}=-\frac{1}{P_{z}(t, T)}\left[\frac{d P_{z}(t, T)}{d r}\right]$

$=-\frac{1}{P_{z}(t, T)} \times\left[-(T-t) \times P_{z}(t, T)\right]$

$=T-t$

Because I know the theory this makes total sense, but I cannot derive it. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Which step of the derivation do you not understand ? That would help to answer you.

Comment: I am getting confused with the general way they derive it i guess, so the:
$\frac{d F}{d x}=A \times a \times e^{a x}=a \times F(x)$

Comment: So I am confused of how we get the $\left[-(T-t) \times P_{z}(t, T)\right]$ from $\left[\frac{d P_{z}(t, T)}{d r}\right]$

Comment: This is a mere application of a calculus rule called chain rule. I let you check Wikipedia but is states that $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Here $z = e^y$ and $y = ax$.

Comment: I know the derivative rules (though, it seems like I don't, really), but i get:
Say F = $-\frac{1}{P_{z}\left(r_{r}, t, T\right)}$

And G = $\left[\frac{d P_{z}(r, t, T)}{d r}\right]$

Derivative of F = $-\frac{1}{P_{z}(r, t, T)}\left[\frac{d P_{z}(r, t, T)}{d r}\right]=-P_{z}(r, t, T)^{-1}=P_{z}(r, t, T)^{-2}\left[\frac{d P_{z}(r, t, T)}{d r}\right]$

Derivative of G = $d P_{z}(r, t, T)^{-d r}=-d r\left(d P_{z}(r, t, T)\right)^{-2 d r}$

So i get = $P_{z}(r, t, T)^{-2}\left[\frac{d P_{z}(r, t, T)}{d r}\right]-d r\left(d P_{z}(r, t, T)\right)^{-2 d r}$

Which just seems wrong

Comment: I did not check your big calculus, yet it seems that you are not calculating the duration but its derivative, am I correct?

Comment: Yes this is only the derivative calculation. My problem might be applying the duration to this derivative calculation. So the mix of the two.
How would you do it, step by step (if it is not too much to ask)

Comment: You just differentiate $P = e^{-r\left(T - t\right)}$ using the chain rule and multiply that derivative by $-\frac{1}{P}$, I cannot imagine a simpler explanation...

Comment: Where does the minus come from? -(T-t).

When i differentiate the $e^{-r(T-t)}$ I change the exponent to: $e^{-r^{^{(T-t)}}}$, and then take the T-t out in front, so i dont get why it should be -(T-t)

Comment: @mbih Perhaps you ought to refresh your calculus class. $P_z=e^{-r(T-t)}$ and, by the chain rule, $P_z'=-(T-t)e^{-r(T-t)}=-(T-t)P_z$. The duration is then $D=-\frac{P_z'}{P_z}=-\frac{-(T-t)P_z}{P_z}=T-t$. Here, $P_z'$ is the derivative of the zero-coupon bond price $P_z$ with respect to the interest rate $r$. The duration measures the time until you receive the bond's cash flows. Since a zero-coupon bond only pays something at maturity, its duration equals the time to maturity.

Comment: @KeSchn you are probably right. When i take the derivative of $e^{-r(T-t)}$ with respect to r, does r become 1, and this makes the -(T-t)?

Comment: In general, if $f(r)=a^{br}$ then $f'(r)=b \ln(a) a^{br}$. That's all what happens here with $a=e$ and $b=-(T-t)$. This is also what siou0107 has mentioned. If you're unfamiliar with this result, you really need to study a maths book but that has nothing to do with finance.

Comment: Got it.
Had forgotten about the rules of e.
Thank you guys very much, had been stuck forever otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

$$P_z\left(r, t, T\right) = e^{-r\left(T - t\right)} \Rightarrow \partial_r P_z = -\left(T - t\right)P \Rightarrow D_{z, T} = T - t$$